# E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apt-get

I'm getting this error message when I'm trying to update Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

```
Hit:1 http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                           
Hit:3 http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                        
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                   
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```